# Seeking ship manifest from Jamaica to Puerto Limon, Costa Rica in late 1860s-1870s?

Tags: manifest, 1860s, 1870s, jamaica

Jamaica to Puerto Limon, Costa Rica: Ship manifest. Where do I find them for the late 1860s-1870s?

where can I find the names of the passengers?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to. Are you able to provide more details of the particular ship and family that you are looking for?